# disabled button

Tags: jquery

I have abutton in my page and I want to disable it. Is there a way to do it?
my code is as follows

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

  $(document).ready(function() {

  var myButton = $(this, "input[type='button']");
  $(myButton).attr("disabled", "true");

  });

</script>

<input id="create" class="button" type="button" >
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#create').attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

Answer (score 6):

Change

```
$(myButton).attr("disabled", "true");
```

to

```
$("#create").attr("disabled", "disabled");
```

When you want to re-enable it

```
$("#create").removeAttr("disabled");
```

Comment: Unless he's using an ancient version of jQuery, using `.prop()` to set the boolean value would be much better.

Comment: Please elaborate on much better. I wasn't aware of the `.prop()` method. Is it recommended over `attr()`?

Comment: Using `.prop()` is like setting `element.something` with `element` being the DOM element. `.attr()` is like calling `element.setAttribute(...)`. While for `disabled` both works, it will not work for things such as the `value` of form elements (even though you'll want to use `.val()` for those anyway)

Answer (score 2):

Use [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) to set the disabled property of the button:

```
myButton.prop('disabled', true);
```

Note that `myButton` is already a jQuery object, so you do not need `$()` around it again. To enable the button again, simply use `myButton.prop('disabled', false);`

Your selector to create `myButton` is wrong, too. Use this instead:

```
var myButton = $("input[type='button']");
```

or even better select it by its ID (faster and also works if you have multiple buttons in your page):

```
var myButton = $('#create');
```

---

So, to keep it short and simple, use the following:

```
$('#create').prop('disabled', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var $myButton = $("input#create");
$myButton.click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if($(this).hasClass("disabled")) {
        // do NOT submit
    } else {
        // submit
    }
});

// somewhere else...
$myButton.addClass("disabled");
```

And use some CSS styling to make the button appear disabled (i.e. `opacity: 0.4` and/or make it grey or something).

Comment: Do not use `something#id` but rather just `#id` - an id needs to be unique anyway so it's unlikely that you have the same id on another element.

Comment: @ThiefMaster: I used it mainly for the semantics so that people reading the above snippet would always know it'd be a certain input element.

Answer (score -1):

I'd use

```
$('#create').attr("disabled", true);
```

without the quotes